# Update Listview in from other fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I am using the tutorial on [Manishkpr](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/) to create a app where you swipe between 1) layoutOne: here you create a file and 2) layoutTwo: shows a listview of all created files in a certain folder.

Problem: if you create a file, it is not immediately shown in the listview. I found that I should use this code in my LayoutOne.java:

```
   LayoutTwo fragment = (LayoutTwo) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TESTTWO");
            fragment.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In LayoutTwo.java I added:

```
private static final String TAG = "TESTTWO";

//and the function getAdapter:

public CustomArrayAdapter getAdapter() {

        return adapter;
    }
```

However, I am getting a nullpointer exception on `fragment.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`. How can I solve this, and is this the best way actually?

**EDIT**

```
myList = new ArrayList<RecordedFile>();

        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File(directory + "/test/");

        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (checkExtension(list[i].getName()) == true) {

                RecordedFile q = new RecordedFile();
                q.setTitle(list[i].getName());
                q.setFileSize(readableFileSize(list[i].length()));


                myList.add(q);
            }
        }

        adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(myContext,
                R.layout.listview_item_row, myList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can anybody help me out? Searching for few days now and getting headaches of it.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am using the tutorial on Manishkpr to create a app where you swipe
>   between 1) layoutOne: here you create a file and 2) layoutTwo: shows a
>   listview of all created files in a certain folder.
>
> Problem: if you create a file, it is not immediately shown in the
>   listview.

If you just have two layouts to swipe that means both will have their views in memory and available to access. You could then assign an id to the `ListView` and when it's time to refresh the data simply look for that `ListView` in the `Activity`, get its adapter and update it, something like this:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheList);
((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

No matter if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter the ListView will not update because it doesn't see the new file, from its point of view the data set is intact. Depending on how your adapter looks like you have two options:

Rebuild the data of the `ListView`, basically redo what you did when the `ListView` is first constructed: check that directory and re-list all files.

```
// create the new file
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File(directory + "/test/");
File list[] = file.listFiles();
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheList);
// I'm assuming your adapter extends ArrayAdapter(?!?)
CustomArrayAdapter caa = (CustomArrayAdapter) list.getAdapter();
caa.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     if (checkExtension(list[i].getName())) {
         RecordedFile q = new RecordedFile();
         q.setTitle(list[i].getName());
         q.setFileSize(readableFileSize(list[i].length()));
         caa.add(q);
     }
}
```

Or you could manually create a `RecordFile` object for the newly created file and add that to the existing adapter:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheList);
(CustomArrayAdapter) caa = (CustomArrayAdapter) list.getAdapter();
File newFile = new File("directory" + "/test/theNewFileName.extension");
RecordFile rf = new RecordFile();
rf.setTitle(newFile.getName());
rf.setFileSize(readableFileSize(newFile.length()));
// have a method to return a reference of the data list(or a method
// to add the data directly in the adapter)
List<RecordFile> data = caa.getListData();
data.add(rf);
caa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I don't know how your adapter looks like so try what I said and if it doesn't work please post the code for the adapter.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in my code, which is good! But it doesn't update the ListView... :s Any ideas?

Comment: @MatthiasVanb Can you explain a bit more about what that `ListView` shows? How does it "see" the files from the specific directory(like at the app's start how does it see the current files)?

Comment: It is basically a listview of the files in a folder which I get by the listFiles() function. I then put the info in an instance of the RecordFile class which I use in my CustomAdapter with a holder to show them at the right place. I edited my question with the code @Luksprog

Comment: I'll try this today @Luksprog, got some delay here :) Ps, any idea what is the most efficient option to choose ?

Comment: @MatthiasVanb From what I posted, the second option is more efficient as you just create the new representation object for the newly created file instead of recreating the objects for the entire directory(first option). On the other hand the first option will give you some control on how the new file will appear(for example if you want the new file to be the first row in the ListView).

Comment: I handled it with the first way! I now have 600 items in the folder, and it is still pretty quick! Thanks for helping me out! WooHOO! You got my 50 points upon your pile! :p @Luksprog

Comment: I found out that if we have listviews in both fragments and we give them the same id's as android.R.id.list, the observer won't work for the listview in the second fragment. So it is advisable to separate the ids. and the adapter should correctly implement the right observer given that these are different from the material design observer in recent APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the viewpager loads the layoutTwo, BUT you do not refresh it with the notifyDataSetChanged. You only refresh the data of the LayoutTwo, but it does not get refreshed, since the viewpager has a  method:   `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` AFAIK this is the default, so the next thing will happen in row: load LayoutOne, load LayoutTwo, do things in layoutOne, do things in layoutTwo. But as you see there will be no load layoutTwo afterwards.

I had a very similar problem and it is a kind of a workaround, but restarted the actvity (and `pager.removeAllViews();` ) and it worked well without disturbing the user.

But to be certain that this causes the problem, put this in your code for a button clicklistener:

```
viewPager.removeAllViews();
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class));
```

This will not solve your problem exactly, but you will able to see if the layoutTwo chaged or not, getting the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had almost the same problem in a project a while ago.

The solution was to add the Observer pattern to the application.

Have a look at the official documentation about the problem:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

What happens is that you register the different `Fragments` with the `Activity` that holds the `Fragments`. Whenever one `Fragment` is changing, you make a `callback` to your `Activity` who in turn will act and deliver some `message` to one of the other `Fragments`.

Then you can get for instance the `ListView` of the specific `Fragment` and update it or whatever you want to do.

It's really simple and powerful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe its a little late but I was struggling to do this and this is the way I managed to do it.

It definitely isn't the best way to do it but it's working.

Initialize your fragments at the start so we can hold each instance of them and then select if we want to instantiate them.

```
ExampleFragment searchFragment = null;
ExampleFragment fileListFragment = null;
```

Now change the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to the following so we use our previously initialiazed Fragments

```
ExampleFragment searchFragment = null;
ExampleFragment fileListFragment = null;
```

Now on the `PagerAdapter` class:

```
class pagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

    public pagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if (searchFragment != null) {
                return searchFragment;
            }
            return searchFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        case 1:
            if (downFragment != null) {
                return downFragment;
            }
            return downFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In this way we can call the methods inside of every fragment and communicate with them from the `Main Activity` without any view or context issue.

Then on the `onTabSelected` method of the action bar or any other `"onChangeTab"` like method you just reset call the method you want from your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    if ((tab.getPosition()) == 1) {
        downFragment.yourMethod();
    }
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

It's not elegant but it is working like a charm.