# startActivityForResult usage for multiple activities

Tags: android

i use startActivityForResult for two activities like this

```
Activity A -> startActivityForResult(ActivityB,0) 
 -> Activity B -> setresult(10); finish();
 -> Activity A -> if(result==10) {
    dofunction();
 }
```

but i must use this logic for 4 or more activities.

```
 Activity A -> startActivityForResult(ActivityB,0) 
 -> Activity B -> finish();
 -> Activity C -> finish(); 
 -> Activity D -> setresult(10); finish();
 -> Activity A -> if(result==10) {
   dofunction(); 
}
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
Activity A -> startActivityForResult(activityB,0);
Activity B -> activityCintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT); startActivity(activityCintent); finish();
Activity C -> activityDintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT); startActivity(activityDintent); finish();
Activity D -> setresult(10); finish();
Activity A -> if(result==10) {dofunction(); } YEPPP
```

this is the logic of FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT. First you start an activity for result, new activity sends this intent to another new activity until you set result.
I hope this will be helpful for people having same problem.

Comment: Does this keep B,C,D on activities back stack until the result it set?
Or does it finish current activity immediately when the next is started?

Answer (score 1):

After naming activity in `startActivityForResult(ActivityB,0)` we give request code for the specified activity ie; `startActivityForResult(ActivityB,REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACTIVITYB)`. with request code being any integer. Then in `onActivityResult` check for each request code and implement your logic

Comment: if you want any reference check to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: i tried 
`Activity A -> startActivityForResult(ActivityB,0) -> Activity B -> startActivityForResult(ActivityC,0) finish(); -> Activity C -> startActivityForResult(ActivityD,0) finish(); -> Activity D -> setresult(10); finish(); -> Activity A -> if(result==10) {dofunction(); }`
but did not work

Comment: you have to specify a 'unique' request code for each activity

Comment: I have to finish all activities over Activity A. so startActivityForResult(ActivityC,0); finish(); is unreasonable. This likes saying a kid "Go to market, bring me icecream but i will not be here when yo return"
I readed 5-6 times your answer NIPHIN, thanks for help, but i still didnot understand

Comment: okay please explain your scenario.... Right now I am guessing you have to start Activity B from A and right when activityD has some result return it to activity A? if thats the case can you start a fresh new activityA from activityD with the obtained results?

Comment: When I start new activity a then if user presses back button application will return old activity a and will see the deleted records.

Comment: Activity a product list, add new product -> activity b select category -> activity c select subcategory -> activity d enter product details return activity a -> refresh product list and see new product in list

Comment: replace activities with fragment other than activityA, then notifydatasetchanged with   listAdapter of activityA after fragment c finishes its job

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924146/update-listview-in-from-other-fragment

Comment: android devices under 3.0 android versiyon does not support fragment. so activities have to stay as activity.

Comment: use android v4 support libraries for that.